# Adding AWS EC2 nodes to Rundeck

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, automation, rundeck

am trying to use the ec2 nodes plugin but having some problem
After putting the jar in libext, i can see the AWS resource model type
I provided the access key and secret key as part of configuration but can't see my nodes in the list.

I know i need to edit some mapping file, something like this:

```
# use Name tag for node name
name.selector=tags/Name
hostname.selector=privateIpAddress
description.default=Ec2 node instance
osArch.selector=architecture
osFamily.selector=platform
osFamily.default=unix
osName.selector=platform
osName.default=Linux
username.selector=tags/Rundeck-User
username.default=root
editUrl.default=https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home#c=EC2&s=Instances
attribute.privateIpAddress.selector=privateIpAddress
attribute.privateDnsName.selector=privateDnsName
tags.selector=tags/Rundeck-Tags
```

But don't know location of this file

Could somebody please help me?

Comment: Just ran into plugin page and got more confused: it seems in project file i need to specify path to mappingFile: Path to a java properties-formatted mapping definition file. Totally lost at this point :) https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-ec2-nodes-plugin

Answer (score 0):

It turned out i needed to add Amazon Endpoint and in mapping parameter in Rundeck properties field i just copied code above, after that, EC2 instance became visible as Rundeck node